# What's the difference between normal types and anonymous types?

Tags: c#, types, anonymous-types

What's the difference between normal types and anonymous types in C#, regarding to compilation process and memory management at runtime? Are anonymous types more inneficient in some way than normal types?

Comment: Efficiency is defined as value produced divided by resources consumed. What value and what resources do you care about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference between normal types and anonymous types in C# regarding memory management at runtime? Are anonymous types more inefficient in some way than normal types?

Anonymous types are neither more nor less than generic internal classes with a constructor, readonly fields, and an implementation of `GetHashCode` and `ToString`. There's nothing special about them as far as the runtime is concerned. The runtime does not know that they are "anonymous"; the runtime sees them as just another class. The generated code is nothing interesting.

> What's the difference between normal types and anonymous types in C#, regarding to compilation process?

I have no idea what this question means to ask.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the last question, it was too broad. I mean, both kind of types are compiled in a different way? maybe one allocates more or less memory than the other? Or there is a significant cost for the compiler to try to figure out if the anonymous type already exists or not when it is used?

Comment: @guillegr123: Well, think like a compiler developer. According to the spec you have to be able to recognize when "the same" anonymous type is used twice in the same assembly, where by "the same" we mean that the number, types and names of the fields are the same and in the same order. How would you implement code that had to keep track of whether two lists of (type, name) pairs were identical or not?

Comment: Thanks. So this means an anonymous type can be re-used in the same scope, if it's used with the same the number, types and names of the fields? Like: `a = new {x=1, y=1};b = new {x=2, y=3};`

Comment: @guillegr123: not only *can* it be re-used, the language specification *requires* that it be re-used. You must be able to say `a = b;` after those two lines and have it work. Moreover, this must be true not just within a method but within an assembly.  So: given that requirement, how would you implement the compiler so that it could figure out that two anonymous types needed to be the same type?

Comment: Maybe having a sort of types dictionary, with their definiton, and checking if the definition exists every time an anonymous type is defined. If that's so, I guess that in the case of normal types, checking for the full name is enough, but in the case of anonymous types, you have to check the full definition.

Comment: @guillegr123: That is basically correct, though checking for full name is insufficient for types. Suppose your program references two assemblies that both have a type named Foo.Bar, for instance. That's a strange situation to be in but it is legal; you can use extern aliases to disambiguate them.  But I digress; yes, the compiler maintains a dictionary mapping from lists of (name, type) tuples to an object that represents the type. Doing so consumes several bytes of memory, which is what you were asking about.

Comment: Thank you very much @Eric Lippert, you pointed me out some very interesting and important things.

Answer (score 12):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):-

> **Anonymous types** provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to first
>   explicitly define a type. The type name is generated by the compiler
>   and is not available at the source code level. The type of the
>   properties is inferred by the compiler.
>
> **Remarks:**
>
> Anonymous types are reference types that derive directly from object.
>   The compiler gives them a name although your application cannot access
>   it. From the perspective of the common language runtime, **an anonymous
>   type is no different from any other reference type, except that it
>   cannot be cast to any type except for object.**

Comment: and can be assigned to a "dynamic", also they can't leave the scope they were created in unless they are assigned to an object or dynamic, however since you can't cast it back out of an object, if you want to return an anonymous object from a function, your function should return the dynamic type.

Comment: @ohmusama: Your claim is commonly believed but is false. Consider the function: `static T M<T>(Func<T> f) { return f(); }` And now call it:  `var anon = M(()=>new { X = 1 });`  The function M creates and returns an object of anonymous type and the caller successfully saves it in a local variable of anonymous type, so your claim that "they can't leave the scope they are created in unless converted to object or dynamic" is false.

Comment: @EricLippert Okay, how do I get it out if I create it IN the function without passing it in. Because that example is the same as saying `var anon = new { X = 1 };`

Comment: @ohmusama: But in my example the instance is not passed in to `M`. A delegate is passed into `M`, the delegate produces the instance, passes it back to `M`, which passes it back to `M`'s caller.

Comment: But OK, if you don't like that then how about this:  `static T N<T>(T t) where T : class { return new { X = 123 }  as T; }` and then `var y = N(new { X = 456 });`.  There, now `N` clearly returns a newly created object but never converts it to `object` or `dynamic`, again demonstrating that your claim is false.

Comment: @EricLippert semantics, seriously though. Say I have a function, and I want to return an anonymous object out of it, without "passing" it in. In your first example you passed in a function that generated it, in your second example you cumbersomely passed in a object with the same prototype. I'm just curious how to get one out without defining it on the outside? Which was my point, because by defining it on the outside of the function seems like a poor use example. I suppose I could see a use for it though... It would be strongly typed!! :)

Comment: @ohmusama: I am being serious. I've used this technique in real programs; it is usually called "cast by example". C# has no syntax for describing an anonymous type aside from creating one. Therefore your only choice should you wish to pass one out in a strongly typed manner is to use type inference on a generic method. Type inference requires an example to make an inference from. Hence: cast by example.

Comment: makes sense, dynamic is the easy way I suppose, (which ASP MVC uses btw).